# customize user profile with ubuntu 22.04 in ad domain with sssd

Tags: 22.04, home-directory, active-directory, sssd

I have joined an ubuntu 22.04 workstation in an AD domain with SSSD.
But I cannot customize the desktop or the screen resolution for domain users.
I tried to put in /etc/skel but it didn't work as if the new user profile was not copied from /etc/skel.

Have I missed something during configuration ?
Thanks for your eventual answers

Comment: `/etc/skel` is used by the `adduser` command to initially populate a newly created User's `$HOME` directory. This is a combined "XY Problem" and a "Solution before Understanding" meta-problem. Read `man adduser`.

Comment: @waltinator Why is `adduser` and `man adduser` relevant here?

Answer (score 1):

I follow [this guide](https://guide.ubuntu-fr.org/server/sssd-ad.html), paragaph Home directories with pam_mkhomedir (optional).

I reconfigured App-armor to add domain users homedir

I copied home from model user to /etc/skel and now, domain users have the same profile as model user

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly handled by [`pam_mkhomedir`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_mkhomedir)

This module can be enabled with `sudo pam-auth-update --enable mkhomedir`. It should by default copy files from `/etc/skel`.